# How to set background to the grids in WPF TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, background, tabcontrol, tabpanel

I'm trying to make a style that sets the background for every grid of every tab in the TabControl I made(the grid under the TabItem).

I've already tried making an empty style but I don't know how to apply it for all of the tabs and where to put it.

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
    <Setter Property="Background"  Value="Beige" />
</Style>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `Style` right, but since you are targeting the background of a `Grid`, you need to set the Type to `Grid`. Also, if you add a Key, you can use it for each Grid within your `TabControl` Items.

```
    <TabControl>
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}" x:Key="TabItemGridBackground">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Beige" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabControl.Items>
            <TabItem Header="Tab1">
                <Grid Style="{StaticResource TabItemGridBackground}">

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab2">
                <Grid Style="{StaticResource TabItemGridBackground}">

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab3">
                <Grid Style="{StaticResource TabItemGridBackground}">

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl.Items>
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! 
Is there a way do to is without copying and pasting it in every <grid>?

Comment: You can remove the x:key from the Style, and remove the Style= from each Grid